# USB-Tethering (Android) shared with VMWare

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, vmware

Because our normal internet provider still takes a couple of days to get it working again, I have to use my Android mobile with USB tethering to access the internet on my Windows 8.1 machine. Unfortunately, when launching CentOS in VMWare Player ("Bridged"), it can't access the internet which worked while it was provided by our cable-bound network. Is there a way to configure VMWare to use the host machine's internet access, too, for the guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to set the network configuration to "NAT".